# Increase Memory

Tags: memory

I'm using a cpu with 256MB ram and Motherboard KT 3 Ultra. MS 6380E Ver. 1

Windows xp home 2002 sp3

I would like to increase the ram.

Can this be done?

Comment: Sure...just buy and install more, assuming you can find that old RAM in stock.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can.  According to MSI's [website](http://us.msi.com/product/mb/KT3-Ultra--Ultra-ARU.html#/?div=Detail) your motherboard can

> • Support six memory banks using three 184-pin DDR DIMMs
>   • Support a
>   maximum memory size up to 3GB
>   • Support 2.5v DDR200/266/333 DDR DRAM
>   DIMM

However, that machine is pretty old.  You might be better off taking the money you were going to spend on RAM and purchasing a newer computer.

Comment: OP might find the needed chips at some PC dump site...